# How can I fetch a value from my database and display it across pages using cookies or similar?

Tags: php, cookies

My website connects to a database of products which each have a unique part number assigned to them (as well as other details such as manufacturer and description).

**For example:**

'Product A' might have a Part Number of '275'.

'Product B' might have a Part Number of '608'.

---

Using a plugin created by our original developer, these part numbers are used to create a page for each product/part number variation automatically (everytime we add new products to the database).

**For example:**

Part Number '275' creates www.mydomain.com/producta/275

Part Number '608' creates www.mydomain.com/productb/608

Each new page is essentially a templated page that adds the product name and part number (as well as manufacturer and description) to various places within a generic product page.

So to retrieve the information from the database and place it into the templated page, we connect to the database and call the product name, part number, manufacturer and description using:

```
$prod = $item['product_name'];
$pn = $item['part_number'];
$man = $item['manufacturer'];
$desc = $item['description'];
```

**What I need**

I would like to create a button such as 'Add to quote' that automatically takes the value of the part number ($pn) from the product page that the user is on and adds it to a form field on another page called My Quote.

The important thing is that not only does the value transfer over to the 'My Quote' page., but that the 'My Quote' page stores the value of the field so that the user can then go to another product page and repeat the process and essentially build a list of parts that they require.

I have looked at somehow utilising cookies for this, by somehow setting the value of the cookie as a variable based on the value of the $pn but I don't think that's possible:

```
Cookies.set("partnumber", "//code here to read the $pn of the page and set as the cookie value", { expires: 7 });
```

I know the above is not correct, but I wonder if there is a way to replace '$pn' with something to read the part number of the page the user is on, then save the cookie on 'Add to Quote' button click and read and display the cookie value within the field on the 'My Quote' form page?

Cookies may not be the way to go so I would appreciate any other ideas. I am farily new to this so apologies in advance for any poor formatting of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$pn` variable is located on the server, while your Javascript code is running at the browser, so you cannot access the variable when the Javascript is executed, this is the problem you have run into, but fortunately it is solvable. You will need a server code, which will run before your Javascript attempts to use this value. You will need to write something like this into a .php file, which will run for a given page:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    var pn = <?php echo $pn; ?>;
    Cookies.set("partnumber", pn, { expires: 7 }); //Assuming that the Cookies prototype exists here and it has a set function, which creates a cookie
</script>
```

This PHP will run on the server and generate the appropriate HTML for you.

You can store the value into `$_SESSION` instead of browser cookies as well and then you will be able to use `$_SESSION["part_number"]`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried adding the .php file you suggested and calling it through to the page using "<script src=pathtofile/filename.php></script>". I have also added a seperate .js file (and again added the script src) which contains "$("#QuoteButton").on("click", function () {$.cookie('Quote_cookie', pn, { expires: 7 });});" to try to create the cookie on the click of a button. However I'm not having any luck with this. Perhaps I am doing something wrong here? Thanks

Comment: @NickM yes, you are doing something wrong. You do not need to create a new PHP file and to link it via HTML. If you do so, your page is already sent to the browser, while you need to initialize the Javascript variable before you sent the page out to the browser. You do not need to link new files, just add the code the a PHP code you already have and which runs. Take a look at this example for more help: https://pagecrafter.com/pass-php-variable-javascript/

Comment: Ok, I think I'm close to working. Now the cookie is registering but rather than the $pn being the value it is 'undefnied':

`<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
// LOAD REQUIRED WP PLUGIN class
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
// DO PLUGIN ACTIVATION CHECK
if ( is_plugin_active('product-item-templates/product-item-templates.php') ) {
// Product Items Template is LOADED >>
?>
<?php $pn = $item['pn'];
?>
var pn = <?php echo $pn;?>;
Cookies.set("partnumber", 'pn', { expires: 7 }); 
<?php
} // END PLUGIN ACTIVATED CHECK
?>
</script>`

Comment: I have now worked out why this wasn't working - it just needed quotes " around the php code that was inside the javascript. So **var pn = <?php echo $pn;?>** becomes  **var pn = "<?php echo $pn;?>"**

Thanks again for all your help

Comment: @NickM you are welcome, if this answer solved your problem, you may want to accept it as the correct answer.